# Powershell sql deploy script is not working with env variavle

Tags: sql-server, powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below line in `constants.groovy` file:

```
myMap = [
    "TEST":["SQL_URL":"Data Source=TEST,123", "credential":"" ]
]
```

This line in `jenkinsfile.groovy`:

```
bat "powershell.exe -file pipeline/powershell/deploy_sql.ps1 ${myMap[env.Environment_Type].SQL_URL}"
```

And this line in `deploy_sql.ps1`:

```
$Env = $args[0]
$msbuild = Start-Process -FilePath "msbuild" -ArgumentList '"Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj"','/t:deploy','/p:Configuration=Release','/p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source="+$Env+";Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"','/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True','/p:TargetDatabase="bnhp_fsdb"','-fl','-flp:logfile=msbuild.log' -wait -PassThru
```

But I get this error in the log:

```
Deploy error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to target server '+$Env+'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
```

When I'm running with the full hard coded Data Source, it works, so I guess something is wrong with the powershell syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell string literals come in two flavors: *verbatim* and *expandable*.

Verbatim string literals are surrounded by single-quotes (`'`), and expandable strings are surrounded by double-quotes (`"`).

Converting the affected string literal to an expandable string requires us to:

- Change surrounding quote marks to `"`
- Escape all literal `"`'s inside the string by *doubling* them
- Escape any remaining special characters with `` ` `` (backtick)

In your case, we would change:

```
'/p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source="+$Env+";Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"'
```

to:

```
"/p:TargetConnectionString=""Data Source=${Env};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"""
```

Comment: Tnx for great answer! would you mind to have a look on another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491118/ssis-deploy-command-doesnt-work-form-powershell-script

Comment: Would you mind to have a look on another similar scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602303/powershell-script-with-ssis-deploy-command-doesnt-work-with-env-variable

Comment: @arielma Same problem, you're using `'` instead of `"`

Comment: yep you are right :). I deleted the question. However, I do have other interesting question (not syntax) regards `SSIS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604718/how-to-have-ssis-exception-in-my-console-log