# SSIS deploy command doesn't work form remote

Tags: ssis, jenkins-pipeline, windows-server

I have the below command which is working from my `CMD`:

```
ISDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:"Integration Services\bin\Development\Integration Services.ispac" /DestinationServer:"TEST,1234" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/TEST/DEVOPS"
```

But when I'm running it thought `Jenkins` on `windows server slave` (after @MisterSmith suggestion, which made me realize it has nothing to do with `powershell`), it doesn't work:

```
bat "ISDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:\"Integration Services\\bin\\Development\\Integration Services.ispac\" /DestinationServer:\"TEST,1234\" /DestinationPath:\"/SSISDB/TEST/DEVOPS\""


Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox.Show(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.WizardMessageBox.Show(Exception error)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Deployment.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: I don't do much with PS, do you need to escape the backslashes in the sourcePath argument?

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work" - what happens? Do you get any errors? If so, what does the error say?

Comment: I don't get any error, but when I'm checking the `SSIS` server, I see the deploy for the `ispac` file didn't work (also, no `DEVOPS` project was created). From `CMD` I can clearly see it works

Comment: The syntax is correct with the exception that you might be better off specifying full paths.  I was able to deploy a project with it by changing it to one of my local projects.  Are you running it interactively?  I was able to see errors from a windows dialogue when it could not find the exe or the project file

Comment: Try appending ` -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt -RedirectStandardError stderr.txt` to your start-process and add the line `gc -Path stdout.txt | write-host; gc -Path stderr.txt | write-host;`. do you get any output? Also try add some `Write-Host` lines to confirm your in the correct directory, that `$env:Path` contains the required folders etc.

Comment: I ran it and got this exception: `Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application`

Comment: Try what @MisterSmith said or running the script interactively from powershell and see what the error is in the modal dialog.  I would guess, it cannot find the exe, the relative project or authentication is failing.  SSISDB needs windows auth.

Comment: I did, see my comment above.

Comment: That error is because ISDeploymentWizard.exe is a bit flaky and doesn't really support `/silent` very well (based on some quick googling). What that error is probably trying to tell you is that the user Jenkins is running your code as doesnt have access. Can you get access to any logs from the other end?

Comment: I'm running on windows slave where `jenkins service` run as my applicative user. I was able to run `SQL` and `SSRS` deploy so far...

Comment: I modified the question. The issue is not `powershell` but running `SSIS` deployment on remote

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to overcome it?